# How to add a space between repeating NgFor components

Tags: html, angular

Newbie Angular question here. I have a parent component which calls a service which returns an array of words. It will then repeat a child component which takes the word and displays it inside a button element. I'd like to be able to put an nbsp; between each repeating button element, but from the parent side of things. I've tried putting various tags between the  tags but none seem to have any effect. Thanks

**Parent** [parent.component.html]

```html
<child *ngFor="let item of items" [word]="item"></child>
```

**Child** [child.component.html]

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{word}}</button>
```

Comment: I wouldn’t necessarily add an nbsp, I would instead add a class to the button and do it in a css way... either add padding or margin to the bottom of each component you generate. That way if you want to increase or decrease the distance, you chance the padding size in your css and it will affect all the buttons.

Comment: Please reproduce this issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the child component instances and include another tag to provide the space inside of the wrapping tag:

**`parent.component.html`**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <child [word]="item"></child>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</ng-container>
```

This would put a space after each and every button element, including the last one, so you may want to provide some way of not setting it for the last element. This could be done using an `*ngIf` conditional, like so:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; last as isLast">
    <child [word]="item"></child>
    <span *ngIf="!isLast">&nbsp;</span>
</ng-container>
```

#### EDIT:

*Use `ng-container` instead of `div` wrapper element. Also, use `ngForOf` `last` variable instead of `index`. Borrowed from comments/other-answer.*

Comment: Thank you, that works. I'm guessing the child tag can only encompass presenting the content of the child component and therefore any extra tags within (from the parent) are ignored. Only by placing presentation logic in an outside div will I see it marked up.

Comment: If you enclose any markup within a component tag, then your component must be designed to project content into it's structure, by using the `ng-content` tag.

Comment: Why don't you use `<ng-container>`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Updated to use `<ng-container>` as that is definitely a more sensible choice here. I left the `<span>` containing the `&nbsp;` because it wouldn't be affected by styling or layout too much already.

Answer (score 5):

I know OP wanted to add an `nbsp;` between child components, but it's worth mentioning that this is not a markup responsibility, rather a CSS/Styling responsibility.

By default the component you embed, `ChildComponent` in your case, will have it's `display` css property set to `inline` which is not affected by vertical margins (top and bottom), by explicitly setting the child `display` property to `block` and applying `margin-bottom` to get the spacing you need; it would also make sense to remove the margin from the last item to get a clean UI, using `:last-child` pseudo-class.

By applying this solution, you could to set the `display` property to `flex` or `inline-block` to spread the child components horizontally in a desktop view, using CSS `media queries`.

```
// parent.css

child {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
child:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will add "," between each element of array. Maybe this logic will help you to achieve this,

```
<span *ngFor="let student of studentList; let last = last;">{{student}}{{last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
```

Feel free to ask questions about my code.